# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec

Tags: java, image, user-interface, netbeans

whenever I tried to had a new package for images and import them this error is shown
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project Juego: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

i do not know why, if I use the local path this doesnt happen, but If I try to have the package with the images it automatically fails.

I try making a package a folder, putting it in the same folder as the proyect but its no use.

I did exactly like indicated in: [https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#:~:text=In%20the%20icon%20property%20dialog,newpackage%20folder%20and%20click%20Finish](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20icon%20property%20dialog,newpackage%20folder%20and%20click%20Finish).

but i dont dont, netbeans its just hard to look at

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.